# ASP.NET gridview delete

Tags: asp.net

I made a quick gridview, bound it to a datasource, put in a select statement it works.

I then went into the datasource, and to the delete tab, and put some delete code in, that ends with where blahUID = @blahUID

I checked the enable deleting checkbox, which added a Delete textlink on each line of the gridview.

However when I press it, it errors because @blahUID is not defined - how can I define it?

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="...snipped..." 


SelectCommand="SELECT [CategoryUID], [WordUID], [CategoryName], [Colour] FROM [Category] WHERE ([WordUID] = @WordUID);" 
DeleteCommand="delete from [Category] where CategoryUID = @CategoryUID">
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="lstWords" Name="WordUID" 
        PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
</SelectParameters>
<DeleteParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="CategoryUID" />
</DeleteParameters>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed by putting DataKeyNames="CategoryUID" in the gridview parameters.

Comment: Very common problem in the world of GridView's.  You must ensure your DataKeyNames are specified.  It also works for multiple keys which is handy.